# axios post request without body getting to the server without the headers

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-headers

the request getting to the server without the headers:

```html
const res = await axios.post(`/api/follow/${props.match.url}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      userId: userId,
    },
});
```

anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2):

should just put null in the body place, and it works